# How would I go about creating a hexagonal prism using OpenTK C#?

Tags: c#, opengl, shapes, opentk

I have only just started using OpenTK and I am also quite new to using C# overall. If anyone could point me in the right direction in terms of a tutorial or how to do it? There are many tutorials for Cube and Triangles but from my understand a shape like this is a whole lot different. Many Thanks.

Comment: If you understand how to draw a cube in OpenTK, then the only difference is the number of faces and their coordinates. So it's purely a mathematical problem at this point and not really a programming problem.

Comment: I am not sure of the mathematical equations behind making these calculations. If you could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

A hexagon can be drawn as [six equilateral triangles sharing a common central point](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.07/h/martin4.html). Finding their coordinates from this central point is simple trigonometry.

Once you can draw a hexagon, draw another hexagon translated at some offset of the first one.

Once can draw two hexagons, draw quads between corresponding pairs of summits (that will be six quads).

You now have a hexagonal prism!

Comment: I have made the two hexagons, however I don't know how to do the quads to connect up the points, any pointers of how this can be done? Thank you.

Comment: A quad is two triangles that form a rectangle. You already have all the coordinates you need since you're just connecting existing points. Not sure what else you don't understand.

Comment: I have used the coordinates to create two hexagons opposite each other in the scene, I know the coordinates to be able to connect them up however it doesn't work properly because I have no idea how to calculate the value for the indices. I am using GetVerts and GetIndices

Comment: Try to work it out on paper, or go back to drawing a cube (it's a prism too, you just start with 2 squares instead of 2 hexagons) and figure out why the indices are the order they are (example: http://www.opentk.com/node/2873 ) The logic really is the same for any kind of prism.